# AsyncTask is not functioning properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I made an audio player which needs to send the web server a constant report of being played (like Geo location, name of the songs etc) for which when I start the music or MediaPlayer calls setOnCompletion to go to the next song. For the first loop it works well, however if the doInBackground stuck then it does execute asynctask for the next time.

```
public void playSong()
{
mMediaPlayer.stop();
mMediaPlayer.reset();           
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.img_btn_pause );
pausePlay.setBackground(myIcon);
if(position == 0){

               mMediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.a);
               mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
               mMediaPlayer.start();
               songName = "IPL Tune";
               }
               if(position == 1){
                   mMediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b);
                   mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                   mMediaPlayer.start();
                   songName = "Saada Haq";
                   }
               if(position == 2){
                   mMediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.c);
                   mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                   mMediaPlayer.start();
                   songName = "Sadda haq(copy)";
    }
             new SendingData().execute();

    }
```

**Code of AsyncTask**

```
private class SendingData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
protected void onPreExecute(){
mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
             android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                     Secure.ANDROID_ID);                  
}          
protected void onPostExecute(Void params){
Log.d("Tesing","After Post");
super.onPostExecute(params);         
}
@Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            sendPost();
            return null;
        }

     }
```

**Code of the Post through Http**

```
public void sendPost()
    {
        Log.d("Testing","in Send Post");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://demos4clients.com/android/musicplayer/index.php");
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", mydate));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", android_id));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", location));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("songname", songName));


  try {
   UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
         request.setEntity(entity);

         HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
   StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
   String line = "";
   String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator); 
   }
   bufferedReader.close();

   Log.d("Response", stringBuffer.toString());



  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   Log.d("Exception of Try",e.toString());

  } 

  finally{
   if (bufferedReader != null){
    try {
     bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }

    }
```

Please advice what to do so that each time a new song is being played asynctask does the task correctly. Does it have anything to do with multiple time calling of asynctask execute?

Comment: Post the stacktrace if there is any

Comment: What do you mean by saying "doInBackground struck"?

Comment: where's your error logcat.

Comment: No there is no error or exception there infact the song playing is smooth however for the third song I dont get the response and while the song repeats (which I want) does not execute the asynctask...

Comment: is it a good practice to call execute asynctask's execute multiple time without knowing the status of the last one or they work on different thread?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set String in your Asynctask instead of Void, and test in logcat if are getting values from your webservice

Comment: shall I put the execute in a runnable so that they would run in different threads?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to accomplish here, but there is definitely a disconnect between what your media player is doing and what your AsyncTask is doing.  For example, you set the song name in your main UI thread (i.e. playSong) but the date and android_id are set by the AsyncTask but stored in the overall (Activity?) scope.  This could really cause you problems in the long run as the AsyncTask runs within its own thread from a pool created automatically by the framework.

Note that AsyncTask's operation as far as multiple instances running in parallel changes based on what version of Android you are running.  In some versions they will run simultaneously, in other cases they are serialized (but still on a separate thread.)  See the "order of execution" section here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Also note that AsyncTasks are not aware of Android lifecycles, so you must manage them appropriately if your Activity or Service gets paused, stopped or destroyed.

My suggestion would be similar to what sulfurid is suggesting: pass the song name to the AsyncTask.  The android_id should be constant for a given device, so pull this one time in your activity.  The date and location you should similarly pull in either your pre-execute or doInBackground callback.